# Angular Directive Element issue

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive in some html something really simple as in:

```
Date Picker<br/>
<div date-picker-extender></div><p></p>
Hello, David!!!
```

The directive itself is a quick sample so it looks like this:

```
app.directive('datePickerExtender', function () {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: true,
     template: '<input size="12" type="text" ng-click="showDatePicker()" />',
     controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.showDatePicker = function () {
            $scope.$root.$broadcast('onShowDatePicker', {});
        };
     }
  }
});
```

The oddest thing is that if I change the restrict to 'E', nothing below the directive in the markup shows up so I don't even the text 'Hello, David!!!'. Of course, changing the restrict to 'E", I change the markup to this:

```
<date-picker-extender />.
```

Can't figure out what the heck is going on.

Ideas?

Comment: can you try changing it to `<date-picker-extender></date-picker-extender>`.

Comment: Do you get similar results if you do what I did? I've seen so many examples where we shouldn't have to do this. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: There's a good discussion here of why Angular can't really do this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953

Comment: Okidoke. Very nice article. Thanks much for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angularjs directives doesnt work with self closing tags: `<date-picker-extender />`

please checkout [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953) for more details.

please use syntax: `<date-picker-extender></date-picker-extender>`